# Offset modifier pushes part of popover outside viewport (Popper)

Tags: vue.js, popper

Using `offset: '0,-30px'` in my Popper modifier. It works but now my popover doesn't fit within the viewport in some situations. Annoyingly, either Popper applies an offset or it ensures popover fits viewport, but not both.

Is there any way to make the `offset` work while Popper still ensures popover fits viewport? (basically telling Popper to apply offset except when doing so creates viewport fit problems)

Comment: You probably need to show a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What version of popper are you using? If I'm not mistaken `offset` requires an object as parameter, not a string.  And yes some example code would help if you work like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the use of offset, please review the documentation for offset. It will simply set the spacing, regardless of the page size.